# indexing interval data with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, categorical-data

I want to select the values of a variable in a pandas dataframe above a certain percentile. I have tried using binned data with pd.cut, but the result of cut is a pandas interval (I think unordered) and I don't know how to select values

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=150), columns=['whatever'])
df_bins=np.linspace(df.min(),df.max(),101)
df['bin']=pd.cut(df.iloc[:,0],df_bins)
```

how to select the rows based on values of the column *bin* ? e.g. >0.95 ?

Comment: well, the question is still "how to index interval data with pandas" that is still unanswered. whatever, I will acept the response and ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need bins, `Pandas` already have [quantile](http://Quantile%20function%20pandas) function.

```
df[df.whatever > df.whatever.quantile(0.95)]
```

Comment: You are right. actually the data I am working with is electricity production by hour, and I wanted to see what % of electricity is produced in the hours of maximum production. that's why I want to bin the data. I will reformulate the question.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if It met your inquiry.